# Horizontal list item width different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, list, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following HTML horizontal list:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#">
                Item1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#">
                Item2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#">
                Item3
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#">
                Item4
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#">
                Item5
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

styled with the following CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 715px;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu > ul {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu > ul > li {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    width: 142px !important;
}
```

Firefox displays it correctly; however, in Chrome all items have width 141px instead of 142. I cannot just increase the number by 1 because then it will be too wide in Firefox and won't fit in one line.

What can I do about it? Please, help.

**EDIT:** Screenshots:
Chrome list: [img694.imageshack.us/img694/5088/chromelist.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5088/chromelist.png)
Firefox list: [img840.imageshack.us/img840/8689/firefoxlist.png](http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/8689/firefoxlist.png)

**EDIT 2:** If I remove border-top and -bottom from 'ul' and add to 'li' then in Chrome it's no longer 141px but... 143px. I have no idea how changing vertical borders could influence width...

Comment: You could always change your width based on the browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html It's lengthy, but it's great for finding out user information. I like it, anyway.

Comment: Screenshots:
Chrome list:
http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5088/chromelist.png
Firefox list:
http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/8689/firefoxlist.png

Comment: @nmagerko I know, but I wanted a standard solution here; if I create user-agent sniffing code in such simple cases then more complicated ones will be a real mess...

Comment: I understand and I absolutely agree. I'll keep thinking/looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `display: table;` they should act the same.

You many need to add `list-style-type:none` and some padding to align the text.

Comment: How then can I achieve vertical align?

Comment: Maybe add a fixed height for the UL say height:50px; then on the li add padding-top:15px; and height: 35px;

Comment: It creates a lot of redundant information... If I want to change list height I'll then need to modify a few things, not one. Isn't there any more elegant solution?...

Comment: I appreciate what your saying but surely you wont be changing your list height that often. Even then it is only 3 values. Personally I would always define the height if I knew it and leave nothing up to chance :)

Comment: Why does it behave in this way, anyway?

P.S. I upped your answer because of this display: table; information but I won't mark it as a solution for now as I still hope for sth a little more elegant...

Comment: Honestly not sure, only made my suggestion based on how I would have approached it. I have been playing around with this till its annoying me :) Will be monitoring this going forward.

Comment: A problem with this approach - what if text doesn't fit in one line? Fixed padding breaks vertical middle align then...